# Stopwatch Elapsed time after thread execution

Tags: stopwatch

In the following code i'm trying to show the elapsed time of stopwatch once the thread execution is finished, but i'm not able to do so

stopwatch's elapsed time is always shown as 0 whether i use thread.isalive or not

How to display elapsed time of stopwatch after execution of a background thread?

```
class Program
{
    static void myfunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("hi after 2 sec");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // create a new stopwatch and start it
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();  

        // make a new thread and start thread execution   
        Thread t = new Thread(myfunction);
        t.Start();

        // I m assuming that the thread t is dead once myfunction is completed

        // display elapsed time when thread has finished work and is dead 
        if (!t.IsAlive)   
           s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", s.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong:

This is because your Thread execution is asynchronous. You tell your program to start the thread (which will execute at least for 2 seconds), then the main Thread continue execution with your `if` statement which is false (the thread is still running in the background).

One way to solve this, is to pass the stopwatch to `myfunction`:

```
static void myfunction(Stopwatch s)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hi");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("hi after 2 sec");
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", s.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString());
}
```

and then in `Main` replace your Thread initialization with:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => myfunction(s));
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and accurate reply :)